# \cmidrule's trim option

Tags: tables, booktabs

The \cmidrule in booktabs package has trim option to specify how much to trim from left or right. However from the following example `\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2}` shows the line is shifted, not shortened; I may be confused about the this trim option, but I expected 2 points from left and right should be removed (trimmed).

The next code `\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-3}` is even more confusing to show that the line is shifted to the left.

How to interpret the trim option with `\cmdrule`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price/lb} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
    a & b & c \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-3}
\morecmidrules
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-3}
\addlinespace[5pt]
    Food& Category & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\$}\\
\midrule
    Apples & Fruit  & 1.50 \\
    Oranges & Fruit & 2.00 \\
\addlinespace
    Beef & Meat     & 4.50 \\
\specialrule{.5pt}{3pt}{3pt}
    x & y & z \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know whether my answer answers your question. I think you're confused by the look of the `\cmidrule`s since you're not using a `\tabcolsep` on the outer edges of the first/last column. That is, you're using `@{}` to suppress it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation of the trim option is correct. What seems confusion here is the fact that removed the column space on the outer edges of your `tabular`.

When considering the `tabular` version *without* the end `\tabcolsep` removed

```
\begin{tabular}{ l l r }
```

[image]

the adjustments for `\cmidrule` using the `l`eft and `r`ight trim options seem more in line with what one would expect.

---

The default trim, if not specified explicitly is `\cmidrulekern` which is set to `.5em`. This equates to `5pt` under the `10pt` (default) document class option, `5.475pt` under `11pt` and `5.87494pt` under `12pt`. Perhaps, instead of specifying trims in absolute values, is a font-related width like `em`.

Answer (score 1):

Without any parameters, the default value for the trim seems to be larger than 2pt to cause the confusion.

When I changed the code not to have any trimming with the following code, I can get the expected trimmed result.

`\cmidrule(l{0pt}r{0pt}){1-2}\cmidrule(l{0pt}r{0pt}){3-3}`

[image]

Comment: Yes, the default trim value is `\cmidrulekern` which is set to `.5em`. You can just use `\cmidrule{1-3}` instead of specifying a `0pt` trim on all sides.

Comment: If this is "the answer to your question", I don't understand how it relates to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2021N (2021-09-01), [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package added support for trim options in its `booktabs` library.

The library provides **ratio values** for trim options `l`, `r`, and `lr`: the possible values of these three options are decimal numbers between `-1` and `0`. The product of the number and `colsep` is the dimension to be trimmed.

Therefore, if you use `@{}` to remove `colsep`, there will be no trimming and no shifting of `cmidrule`.

Note that you need to put trim options `l`, `r`, and `lr` inside **square brackets** with `tabularry`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{booktabs package}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price/lb} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
    a & b & c \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-3}
\morecmidrules
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-3}
\addlinespace[5pt]
    Food& Category & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\$}\\
\midrule
    Apples & Fruit  & 1.50 \\
    Oranges & Fruit & 2.00 \\
\addlinespace
    Beef & Meat     & 4.50 \\
\specialrule{.5pt}{3pt}{3pt}
    x & y & z \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\section{booktabs library in tabularray package}

\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec = {@{}llr@{}},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{c}, % multicolumn
  cell{1}{3} = {c},
  cell{3}{3} = {c},
}
\toprule
  Item    &          & Price/lb \\
\cmidrule[r]{1-2}\cmidrule[l]{3}
  a       & b        & c        \\
\cmidrule[lr=-0.5]{1-2}\cmidrule[lr=-0.5]{3}
\morecmidrules
\cmidrule[lr=-0.5]{2-3}
\addlinespace[5pt]
  Food    & Category & \$       \\
\midrule
  Apples  & Fruit    & 1.50     \\
  Oranges & Fruit    & 2.00     \\
\addlinespace
  Beef    & Meat     & 4.50     \\
\specialrule{.5pt}{3pt}{3pt}
  x       & y        & z        \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

[image]