# tabularray \cmidrule trim option not working

Tags: tables, tabularray

I'm trying to use the trim option with tabularray, and I can't understand why it's not working. I read another [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336858/cmidrules-trim-option) about it which didn't help me.   What am I doing wrong?

```
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[t]
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l] *{6}{X[c]}}}
            &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{multicol1} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{multicol2} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{multicol3}\\
          \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5} \cmidrule[r]{6-7}
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Caption}
        \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

This is the output I get:

[image: this is the output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full and compilable example. You should place `\usepackage{tabularray} \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}` in your preamble.

Comment: My bad, edited. Thanks

Comment: Well, if I add `\documentclass{article}` (just my guess) before and `\end{document}` after your code, it compiles fine. I don't get the output you get, but the lines are rendered correctly.

Comment: I had \documentclass{report}, switched to article and still same result. If it can help, I am using overleaf as compiler.

Comment: You may use `report`, this should not be a problem. Do you load the document class with any options? Is your TeX installation up to date?

Comment: I have assumed that overleaf has been updated to the latest version. I'm new to Latex, so I have a lot to learn. No, the document class has no options. 
Is there another package to compile the table as I would like?

Comment: I tested it with TexMaker, and it works. I guess it's an overleaf problem at this point.

Comment: You may find the latest `tabularray.sty` file in this [github respiratory](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/blob/main/tabularray.sty). Put this file in your Overleaf project folder (where your tex file is).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

- Overleaf have so far installed old `tabularray` package version 2021L, which not support `\cmidrule[r]{2-3}` from your code fragment (see comment of @L.J.R., who is package author).
- Support for trim option (shortening) of  `\cmidrule` is available with `tabularray` version 2021N and latter (see package author  [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336858/cmidrules-trim-option)).
- Transcript of your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example) with pure `tabularray` syntax is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l] *{6}{X[c]}}}
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  multicol1   &
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  multicol2   &
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  multicol3   &   \\
  \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5} \cmidrule[r]{6-7}
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\      % <--- added row
\end{tblr}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives after compilation with recent `tabularray` package version (2021Q) the following result:

[image]

This result you will get also with use of older version of the `tabularray` package, but not older as 2021N.

Comment: I tested it recently and found that Overleaf had `tabularray` 2021L (2021-07-01) which was too old.

Comment: @L.J.R., interestingly. I tested showed MWE in my Overleaf account and got error `LaTeX Error: File *tabularray.sty* not found. The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.`

Comment: Overleaf won't change TeX Live version for old projects. You may try to create a new project and test it again.

Comment: @L.J.R., yo are right. I use an old project for text. With creating a new project I have the same result as you noted. Thank you very much for info.